# How to customize options in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) but I have a data in object not in array & in options only accepting array values. How can I solve it?

```
 <Select
   options={ccUsers}
   onChange={handleChange}
 />
```

**Working data :-**

```
  const ccUsers = [
    { value: 'One', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'Two', label: 'Two' },
  ];
```

**But getting data in this format :-**

```
const ccUsers = {
    "test": "testing",
    "test": "testing"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert into Array

```js
const obj = {
  'One': 'One',
  'Two': 'Two',
};
const ccUsers = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
  label: key,
  value
}))
console.log('>>>>>  ccUsers : ', ccUsers);
```

Comment: How to add ccUsers in useState ?

Comment: you dont need useState, you can directly write in  `options`

Answer (score 0):

It accepts an array of `{value: string, label:string}` like many other Select components, such as antd Select. You need to transform your data before sending it as a prop inside Select. Since you have key-value pairs in an object already, you can use `Object.entries()` to do that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries